# Xamarin & Multiple Filepicker

Tags: ios, xamarin, uwp, upload, filepicker

i'm building a project on Xamarin. Right now i have a big issue. I need to browse user's computer for upload any file. He can of course upload multiple files. As i know Xamarin does not provide browsing of all the system but just its. So i tried to find a way with some drag n drop, i didn't find. I tried a filepicker but he let me pick just one file (my client would upload 100 files at once) so it doesn't fit to what i need. Finally i decided to do my own browsing system but it takes forever to browse because of the UI. Do you have any solution for me ? I would appreciate a package with a filepicker that allow multiple files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the class [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker?view=winrt-18362) in UWP ?

It supports to pick multiple files , check the method [FileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.pickmultiplefilesasync?view=winrt-18362#Windows_Storage_Pickers_FileOpenPicker_PickMultipleFilesAsync).

#### Sample

1. Define interface in Forms project

   ```
   public interface MyFilePicker
   {
       Task OpenFilePickerAsync();
   }
   ```
2. Implement in UWP project

   ```
   [assembly: Dependency(typeof(UWPFilePicker))]
   namespace App24.UWP
   {
       class UWPFilePicker : MyFilePicker
       {
           public async Task OpenFilePickerAsync()
           {
               var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
               openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
               openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
               openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
               openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
               openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
               IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await openPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
               if (files.Count > 0)
               {
                   StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Picked files:\n");
                   // Application now has read/write access to the picked file(s)

               }
               else
               {
                   return;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call it in Forms project

   ```
   private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       MyFilePicker service = DependencyService.Get<MyFilePicker>();
       await service.OpenFilePickerAsync();
   }
   ```

Comment: but is it crossplatform ? Or should i do code for IOS & UWP ?

Comment: It is only used in UWP , you can create dependency service to call it .

Comment: can you explain please it is really interesting ?

Comment: imma trying to make it work but i can't i have an error iAsyncOperation . I think your solutin with a dependency service is more useful but i don't know how to implement it

Comment: Check the tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction , it's just a way to call native api from specific platform .

Comment: I find the Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker but it can not pick multiple file

Comment: yes i saw it, it doesn't fit what i need @lindexi but thanks. Gonna check your tutorial Cole thanks

Comment: Check the simple sample .